# Circulant-like determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, circulant-matrices

Let $a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{C}$. How can I compute the following determinant?

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_{n-1} \\
-a_{n-1} & a_0 & a_1 & \dots & a_{n-2} \\
-a_{n-2} & -a_{n-1} & a_0 & \dots & a_{n-3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-a_1 & -a_2 & a_3& \dots & a_{0} \\
\end{vmatrix}_{(n)}$$

Comment: What is the structure?  Circulant-looking but with sign-reversal below the main diagonal?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes. I don't know if there is a specific name for this type of determinant.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)#Schur_product_theorem may give you a bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\zeta\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\zeta^{2n}=1=-\zeta^n$. I think, $v=(1,\zeta,\ldots,\zeta^{n-1})$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\zeta^k$. Now let $\zeta:=e^{\pi i/n}$. This should give
$$\det A=\prod_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}a_l\zeta^{l(2k-1)}.$$

**Added on request:** Argument without eigenvalues adapted from [Determinant of cyclic matrix, proof without eigenvectors.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305771/determinant-of-cyclic-matrix-proof-without-eigenvectors). Let $f(\omega)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\omega^k$ and $M=(\zeta^{(k-1)(2l-1)})_{k,l=1}^n$. Then
$$AM=\begin{pmatrix}
f(\zeta)&f(\zeta^3)&\cdots&f(\zeta^{2n-1})\\
\zeta f(\zeta)&\zeta^3f(\zeta^3)&\cdots&\zeta^{2n-1}f(\zeta^{2n-1})\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
\zeta^{n-1}f(\zeta)&\zeta^{3(n-1)}f(\zeta^3)&\cdots&\zeta^{(n-1)(2n-1)}f(\zeta^{2n-1}).
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since the determinant is linear in every column, we can factor out $f(\zeta)$, $f(\zeta^3)$ and so on,
$$\det(A)\det(M)=\det(AM)=f(\zeta)f(\zeta^3)\ldots f(\zeta^{2n-1})\det(M).$$
Since $M$ is an invertible Vandermonde matrix, $\det(M)\ne 0$ and $\det(A)=f(\zeta)f(\zeta^3)\ldots f(\zeta^{2n-1})$.

Comment: Another method without eigenvector exists?

Comment: You can try to adapt this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305771/determinant-of-cyclic-matrix-proof-without-eigenvectors

Comment: I thought of trying this method too, but I didn't get any results

Comment: It's not clear to me why you want to avoid eigenvalues, but I've added the alternative argument anyway.