# What is the class of matrices diagonalizable by "generalized FFT"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, fourier-transform, diagonalization

As a [well-known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601168/diagonalization-of-circulant-matrices) fact, a matrix is circulant if and only if it has a representation of the form $F^{-1}DF$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $F$ is a discrete Fourier transformation.
In other words, the class of matrices diagonalizable by FFT are circulant matrices.

Recall that the FFT algorithm has $\log_2(N)$ steps, where $N$ is the dimension of the input vector, i.e. $F$ can be written as the composition of

\begin{equation}
F = F_1 \circ F_2 \circ \cdots \circ F_{\log(N) - 1} \circ F_{\log_2(N)}
\end{equation}

By "generalized FFT", I mean something like

\begin{equation}
F_\theta = F_1 \circ D_1 \circ P_1 \circ F_2 \circ \cdots \circ F_{\log_2(N) - 1} \circ D_{\log_2(N)-1} \circ P_{\log_2(N)-1} \circ F_{\log_2(N)}
\end{equation}

where $D_i$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements all have magnitude 1 and $P_i$ is a permutation matrix for $1 \le i \le \log_2(N)-1$. Note that $F_\theta$ is orthogonal (because it's a product of multiple orthogonal matrices) and parameterized by $\theta = \{(D_i, P_i): 1 \le i \le \log_2(N)-1\}$.

**Question**: what is the class of matrices diagonalizable by "generalized FFT"? In other words, do matrices of the form $F_\theta^{-1} D F_\theta$ have any special structure, besides the fact that they encompass the class of circulant matrices?